# For AWS EC2, AMI Backup. when doing backup does the server itself stop or suspend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-ami

I need to do an AMI backup from one of our EC2 server,
my concern is, if during AMI backup. do the server stop or suspend?

or the server does the AMI backup without any interruption at all?

Answer (score 0):

By default creating an AMI reboots the instance but there check-box that says “No Reboot”, alternatively with *aws cli* there’s a `--no-reboot` parameter.

However note that not rebooting may cause inconsistent backups (that’s the nature of OS filesystem caching, not AWS fault).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you for your help @MLu

Comment: @RonaldRepolona Glad I could help. If you’re happy with the answer please upvote and accept it. Thanks!